# Excel: How many lines in the vertical direction by adding this

Tags: excel, count

Is it possible to know how many rows are being added in the vertical direction?

In the example we are adding 13 rows.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUBTOTAL(2,B1:B13)` or `ROWS(B1:B13)` or maybe even `COUNTIF(B1:B13,">0")`.

But as a suggestion - play a bit more with what you find, before asking about very basic formulas, which excel-help or google would have provided you way faster.